# Convergence in laws versus convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

For rvs $X_{n}$ in metric space S, convergence in laws means $\int f(X_{n})dP\to \int f(X)dP$ for $f\in C_{b}(S)$ whereas in distribution means $F_{X_{n}}\to F_{X}$.

In Dudley page 296, for example even though we have convergence in laws $\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}\to \delta_{0}$, we don't have convergence in their distributions because $\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$ are not continuous at 0.

Can you provide any other intuitive examples?

Also any equivalent definitions for convergence in laws.

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot to be said here; more commonly "convergence in laws" is called "weak convergence". The basic theorem about equivalent conditions is called the portmanteau theorem, which you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures See the following section for how to translate this statement into a statement about random variables.

Comment: Also, can you write the paragraph in question? If I recall (I may be half-awake and making a silly error) $\delta_{1/n}$ converges in distribution, in the sense that the CDFs of $\delta_{1/n}$ converge to the CDF of $\delta_0$ everywhere except at $0$, which is not a continuity point of $\delta_0$ and therefore not a problem. But they do not converge in any stronger sense than that (e.g. total variation or a.s.)

Comment: Indeed, convergence in distribution does not mean $F_{X_{n}}\to F_{X}$ pointwise.